# Loading font in Monogame

Tags: c#, monogame, fonts, spritefont

This question is probably a duplicate but I'm still asking it since it's all yesterday that I'm trying to get this done without any success. I followed many solutions and tried even more libraries which were either outdated or they simply didn't work.
Right now the most reasonable method I found is

- Open the Content Pipeline;
- Create a new Content if there isn't any;
- Right click on Content -> Add -> New item -> SpriteFont Description
  -> Give it a name;
- Click Build;
- Go to the output directory, grab the XNB file that was created and
  put it in some folder of the project, under Content;
- Change the properties to Content and Copy if newer;

And I use it like this:

```
private SpriteFont font;

font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("NameOfXNBFile");

spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend, null, null, null, null, Global.Camera.TranslationMatrix);

spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Some Text", new Vector2(100, 100), Color.White);

spriteBatch.End();
```

I don't have any errors, the text is simply not shown. I think I could be close to a solution since one and only one single time the text appeared, but as the fool I am I happily closed the tabs of countless tutorials and made some changes which led the text to never show again.

Comment: Seems fine to me.  Are you drawing anything else that could potentially draw over top the font?  Are you sure position 100,100 is visible on screen ?

Comment: Ok your comment led me to try and twist something and I found something: the text is drawn but with a fontsize of something like 5 so it's nearly unnoticeable but mostly I may have misunderstood what drawing font is for since it stays anchored on the ground. What I wanted was instead something HUD-like.
Anyway thank you to make me recognize my error, if you know how to change fontsize and other properties like the font itself (I don't like Arial this much) I would be extremely happy.

Comment: To change font size, simply drag the `.spritefont` file into visual studio's code editor and edit the properties there. It's a mere `.xml` file and has comments that will guide you on how to change the font and the size of the characters and even their styling.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> What I wanted was instead something HUD-like.

To make it always appear on top, simply draw it last.

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
spriteBatch.Draw(someTexture,...);
spriteBatch.DrawString(...); //Will overwrite someTexture
spriteBatch.End();
```

Alternatively, there are overloads for `Draw(...)`, `DrawString(...)`, etc. that allow you to specify the layer depth used by spritebatch to sort sprites.

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
spriteBatch.DrawString(,,,,,,,,,0); //Will overwrite someTexture
spriteBatch.Draw(someTexture,,,,,,,,100);
spriteBatch.End();
```

But you can also use multiple batches:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
spriteBatch.DrawString(,,,,,,,,0);
spriteBatch.End();
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
spriteBatch.Draw(someTexture,,,,,,,,100); //Different batch; will overwrite text
spriteBatch.End();
```

> if you know how to change fontsize and other properties like the font itself (I don't like Arial this much) I would be extremely happy.

- Right click on Content -> Add -> New item -> SpriteFont Description -> Give it a name;

This creates a `.spritefont` file which contains very simple XML pointing to a particular [font]-[size] which is then used to build the XNB spritesheet. You can edit the `.spritefont` file with Notepad.